# Flutter requests using Certificates and SSL

Tags: flutter, dart, postman, flutter-dependencies

i'm trying to send an GET/POST request from flutter to myapp service.
right now i'm doing it from POSTMAN, I have configured **CA Certificate**, and a **Client Certificates** with 3 configurations:(Host, Crt File, Key File).

now in POSTMAN it works great i receive the response.
on flutter i'm not sure how to pull this 3 files and create the Get request to get the Response.

any help on how i can achieve it in flutter?

i tried this:

```
void getAPI() {
  var url = "https://controller.test.io/v1/";
  SecurityContext context = SecurityContext();
  context.setTrustedCertificates("/Users/me/keys/crtfile");
  context.usePrivateKey("/Users/me/keys/keyfile");
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient(context: context);
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
      .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
      print(contents);
    });
  });
}
```

but i get this:

```
Cannot open file, path = '/Users/me/keys/crtfile' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

**#attempt 2:**

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}


Future<void> getdata() async {
  var url = "https://controller.mine.try/api/v1";
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  SecurityContext context = SecurityContext();
  HttpClient client = HttpClient(context: context);
  client.maxConnectionsPerHost=5;
  try {
    HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    final stringData = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    print(stringData);
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
```

**Result:**

```
Unhandled Exception: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri
```

Comment: In a plain Dart project, read the bytes from the file and use `usePrivateKeyBytes`. Test that works. Then, in Flutter, add the files as assets, load them (you'll end up with `ByteData` so convert to bytes with `.buffer.asUint8List()`) and continue as above. There's a good chance you don't want to put a private key in assets in a production app - and you may need to think of a different way to authenticate the client rather than a client cert.

Comment: i'm not sure how to do all of the steps you mention. can you show me with code please? @RichardHeap
the app is going to be localy. i don't want to put the crt online,they can be pulled only from the local pc.

Comment: This question already covers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300017/dart-add-ssl-certificate-and-key-to-httpclient

Comment: @RichardHeap i tried but it request asset.
i want the user to choose the path from his pc. can it be done?
The user already can pick the path and i can use the path.
but how i use it in : rootBundle.load?

Comment: Check out: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Comment: @RichardHeap i already using it, i got the path.
but the rootBundle accept only asset folder path ?

Comment: Sounds like a MacOS permission error, as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479686/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-after-macos-catalina-update

Comment: @RichardHeap nope, not working. i'm not sure why.
i'm using macos desktop debuger.

Comment: You may have more luck if you question actually describes the problem, which is: cannot open and read a file, picked by file_picker, in Flutter desktop on MacOS. It's not really a certificate or TLS problem. Maybe make a new question tailored to the specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to configure ca file. Just do it in the below way. It worked perfectly in my project.

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
 
  runApp(
     MyApp()
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it with my code?
how does it not require a ca or a key file ? my Endpoint is requires this auth way. just like i use in postman...

Comment: i have added the second attempt to the main post, can you have a look please?

Comment: Please add your main function. Please check my code.

Comment: what do you mean by main func ?

Comment: main() this function

Comment: This worked for me like a charm, Faisal! Take my happiest upvote ever, man! 10x a lot!

Comment: Don't use this! It just bypasses all certificate check and approves all http connections